# Find a string in Perforce file without syncing

Tags: perforce

Not sure if this is possible or not, but I figured I'd ask to see if anyone knows.  Is it possible to find a file containing a string in a Perforce repository?  Specifically, is it possible to do so *without* syncing the entire repository to a local directory first?  (It's quite large - I don't think I'd have room even if I deleted lots of stuff - that's what the archive servers are for anyhow.)

There's any number of tools that can search through files in a local directory (I personally use Agent Ransack, but it's just one of many), but these will *not* search a remote Perforce directory, unless there's some (preferably free) tool I'm not aware of that has this capability, or maybe some hidden feature within Perforce itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`p4 grep` is your friend. From the [perforce blog](http://www.perforce.com/blog/100712/p4-grep)

> 'p4 grep' allows users to use simple file searches as well as regular
>   expressions to search through file contents of head as well as earlier
>   revisions of files stored on the server. While not every single option
>   of a standard grep is supported, the most important options are
>   available. Here is the syntax of the command according to 'p4 help
>   grep':

```
p4 grep [ -a -i -n -v -A after -B before -C context -l -L -t -s -F -G ] -e pattern file[revRange]...
```

See also, [the manual page](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/grep.html).

**Update:** Note that there is a limitation on the number of files that Perforce will search in a single `p4 grep` command. Presumably this is to help keep the load on the server down. This manifests as an error:

```
Grep revision limit exceeded (over 10000).
```

If you have sufficient perforce permissions, you can use [`p4 configure`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/configure.html) to increase the `dm.grep.maxrevs` setting from this default of 10K to something larger. e.g. to set to 1 million:

```
p4 configure set dm.grep.maxrevs=1M
```

If you do not have permission to change this, you can work around it by splitting the `p4 grep` up into multiple commands over the subdirectories. You may have need to split further into sub-subdirectories etc depending on your depot structure.

For example, this command can be used at a bash shell to search each subdirectory of `//depot/trunk` one at a time. Makes use of the [`p4 dirs`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/dirs.html) command to obtain the list of subdirectories from the server.

```
for dir in $(p4 dirs //depot/trunk/*); do
  p4 grep -s -i -e the_search_string $dir/...
done
```

Comment: Oops, you posted this while I was answering my own question.  Thanks though.

Comment: No problem, glad you found the answer. Now you just need to find that pesky string ;)

Comment: I'll give you the checkmark, I guess, because your answer is slightly more detailed than mine, including the manual link.

Comment: I've just updated with the workaround for the `Grep revision limit exceeded` error message because that is quite often encountered when using `p4 grep`.

Comment: @Day, instead of breaking up your grep into multiple commands, you can also reset the dm.grep.maxrevs configurable to a higher value.

Comment: @Bryan If you have access to the server config, then yes you can. In my experience, most companies that are enterprisey enough to pay for perforce don't let the devs change such things and won't change it for them at the drop of a hat. The multiple commands trick will always work while you wait for your "server configuration change request" to get approved :) I've updated the answer with this info though, as it would certainly be easier if you can do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, solved this one myself.  `p4 grep` indeed does the trick.  *[Doc here](http://www.perforce.com/blog/100712/p4-grep)*.  You have to carefully narrow it down before it'll work properly - on our server at least you have to get it down to < 10000 files.  I also had to redirect the output to a file instead of printing it out in the console, adding `> output.txt`, because there's a limit of 4096 chars per line in the console and the file paths are quite long.

Comment: [Here's a trick](https://gist.github.com/3750767) to help you get around the file limit by grepping through each top level dir one at a time. Adapt to suit.

Comment: Neat - If I need to do this again I might try that, though I'm afraid if I do this kind of thing too often I might get an angry call from the IT people for using too much CPU time on the servers...

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you can do with the standard perforce tools.  One helpful command might be `p4 print` but it's not really faster than syncing I would think.

Comment: It's not a matter of speed, so much as disk space.  I looked up `p4 grep` which seems like it might do the trick, but I don't seem to have permissions set up to do that.  (And getting p4 permissions around here is like pulling teeth, so I'd rather not go through that again.)  It might work if I can narrow down the search enough...

Comment: I'm embarrassed I forgot about `p4 grep`, I was one of the people clamoring for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big if but if you have access to the server you can run agent ransack on the perforce directory. Perforce stores all versioned files on disk, it's only the metadata that's in a database.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure there's no way I'd ever get that kind of access.  It took over a week just to get Perforce access on this folder...

Comment: How often do you have to do this? Once, every hour, once a week? Perhaps you could download batches of files to search

Comment: Well, so far, in the 3 1/2 months I've been here - once.  The code I needed to search was not the current code (which I do have locally), but an older archived version.  Old enough that the majority of the people who worked on it are no longer working here, and nobody even knew how to get permissions...  It's a big company, lots of stuff like this falls through the cracks sometimes.

Comment: Perforce gets a bad name because of bad admins, sounds like you're suffering that problem.  See if you can get one of your IT support guys to take up your case and get you permissions to the old version, then sync parts of the code until you find the string you want.