# How do I full text index/search source code in our Perforce depot?

Tags: perforce

We use Perforce, recent build (2015.2, we could update to newer if need), on Win2012-R2 server.

We would like full text search to easily find strings across the code base (.cs, .aspx, .less, .resx, etc)

What is an appropriate approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be: p4search

However, where it could be a cool 20-30 minute setup, plan on taking 4+ hours over 1-2 days.

Worse, p4search has been abandoned by perforce. It does not install our run properly on current linux (e.g. Centos 7), requiring edits to startup scripts and general hassle. The indexer gets hung on some files, rdeep diagnostics.

After screwing around w it for a week, we gave up.

So the answer is:

1) Use Open Grok: https://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/

or

2) Prepare for a long haul to set up p4search (which, fwiw, also requires perforce Swarm, so you will be setting that up also)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of such tools out there. Here are two you could start investigating:

1. Open Grok: https://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/
2. P4Search: https://www.perforce.com/company/newsletter/2014/02/p4-search-search-perforce-server

Comment: opengrok looks interesting!  p4 search is, at least in windows server env, unusable from what I can see.

Comment: Worth finding a *nix box. P4Search saves SO much time.

Comment: @tkosinski I love the idea of p4 search, and am happy to set it up on a *nix box. But p4d itself is on win, and that is not so easy to move.  It appears, from my review, that having p4d on win is a deal breaker for p4search.

Comment: @tkosinski I should also add that p4 search appears to have been abandoned by perforce. There appears to be zero maint on it.

Comment: @Jonesome I'm also running p4d on Windows.  Yes, it's my understanding that there are now (at least 2 flavors) -- the original P4Search which was put on its open source site: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4search/activity/  as well as the most recent put out by Perforce, the Helix Search Tool:  https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix#server-components   I have not yet tried the latter.

Comment: @tkosinski : perforce.com/downloads/helix#server-components looks good, they have a 2016.1 release of p4search there... I am going to try that one!

Comment: @tkosinski Well, have been dorking w p4search all day. Pathetic install/setup docs. Amazing they got away with such poor docs. May yet get it working.

Comment: @Jonesome I cannot disagree. I can get a new p4 database set up in a couple of minutes, yet p4search was painful. Totally worth it, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the built-in p4 grep (perforce [docs](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_grep.html)), with some limitations, see e.g. this [good answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693937/109787), in the server since 2010.1.